# Does a Greek need a visa to visit Seoul or Moscow or Singapore?

Tags: visas, russia, south-korea, singapore, greek-citizens

I have a Greek passport and plan to go to Thailand via Seoul, Moscow or Singapore. Before I book my ticket for city break, for which of these cities DON'T I need a visa (transit or tourist)?

Comment: You can visit a seaports in Russia as a ferry traveler, for example, Saint Petersburg, but not the Russia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, and many other European nationals, are allowed in to Seoul (up to 90 days), according to [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mofa.go.kr/ENG/visa/Visa_Exemption/index.jsp):

> [Schengen countries (except for Slovenia out of the 26 Schengen
>   countries)], Austria (Diplomatic/Official: 180 days), Belgium, Czech
>   Republic, France, Germany, **Greece**, Hungary, Italy, Liechtenstein,
>   Lithuania, Latvia, Luxemburg, Malta, Netherlands, Poland, Portugal
>   (60days), Slovakia, Spain, Switzerland
>   ※ Denmark, Estonia, Finland, Iceland, Norway, Sweden (90 days within 180 days)

Comment: Thank you pnut. The answer is only for Seoul(i don t need any visa). Maybe also you know for Moskow or Singapor?